# Can I have Autosys send an alert if a job doesn't end at a specific time?

Tags: autosys

I have a box job that is dependent on another job finishing. The first job normally finishes by 11pm and my box job then kicks off and finishes in about 15 minutes. Occasionally, however, the job may not finish until much later. If it finishes later than 4am, I'd like to have it send an alert.

My admin told me that since it is dependent on a prior job, and not set to start at a specific time, it is not possible to set a time-based alert. Is this true? Does anybody have a workaround they can suggest? I'd rather not set the alert on the prior job (suggested by my admin) as that may not always catch those instances when my job runs longer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up adding a job to the box with a start time of 4am that checks for the existence of the files the rest of the job creates. We also did this for the jobs predecessors to make sure we are notified if we are at risk of not finishing by 4am.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a max run alarm time which will alert if that time is exceeded